# Selected option loosed red color

Tags: html, css, xhtml

So I have a select element with multiple option elements. All option elements except one have:

```
color: black;
```

One option has:

```
color: red;
```

For example:

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value="1" class="textBlack">1</option>
    <option value="2" class="textBlack">2</option>
    <option value="3" class="textRed">3</option>
    <option value="4" class="textBlack">4</option>
</select>
```

The problem is I would want the option with red text to stay red after being selected. So when HTML in DOM looks like this (i.e. I click on the select element and choose the red option):

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value="1" class="textBlack">1</option>
    <option value="2" class="textBlack">2</option>
    <option value="3" class="textRed" selected="selected">3</option>
    <option value="4" class="textBlack">4</option>
</select>
```

I would like the text in the select element to be red as well. However the text is black.

Comment: It's `color` not `text-color`.

Comment: @BoltClock I know, it was just a typo. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with pure css I don't think it's possible. You can use `select {color:red}` but this will color red all the `option`. To achieve what you need probably will need javascript, an example of jQuery code is below:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var current = $("select option:selected").attr("value");
    if (current == 3) {$("select").css('color','red');} else {$("select").css('color','black');}
});
$("select").click(function() {
    $("select option").css('color','black');
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/xrPKN/2/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the color of the select via JavaScript then. Something like

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $(this).css("color", $(this).children("option:selected").css("color")); 
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.textRed{color:red}
```

Very simple, unless im missing something?